# How can I use the new ESLint flat config in a Next.js project and also use 'canonical' rules?

Tags: typescript, next.js, eslint, typescript-eslint, eslintrc

I have a TypeScript Next.js project called K that uses the built-in Next.js ESLint rules + "extends" a 3rd-party package that includes rules from [Canonical](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-config-canonical#canonical-eslint-config), etc.

I want to:

1. Create my own 3rd-party package (using TypeScript) that consists of Next.js ESLint rules + some rules from Canonical, etc, and I want it to use the new ESLint "flat config".
2. Change my K project to use the new ESLint "flat config" and have NO rules defined locally in that project but instead important all rules from my new package.

I've read:

- https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-2/
- https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new
- https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/eslint

But I've still been unable to figure out what to do.

Below is my `src/eslint.config.ts` which I transpile to `eslint.config.js`.

```ts
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

import { FlatCompat } from '@eslint/eslintrc';
import typeScriptEslintPlugin from '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin';
import tsParser from '@typescript-eslint/parser';
import { type Linter } from 'eslint';
import functional from 'eslint-plugin-functional';
import globals from 'globals';
// import eslintPluginImport from 'eslint-plugin-import'; // Seems unnecessary. Maybe it's included in the 'canonical'?

// mimic CommonJS variables -- not needed if using CommonJS
const filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const dirname = path.dirname(filename);

const compat = new FlatCompat({
  baseDirectory: dirname,
});

const customRules = {
  '@babel/object-curly-spacing': 'off',
  'array-bracket-newline': 'off',
  'array-element-newline': 'off',
  'func-style': 'off',
  'line-comment-position': 'off',
  // https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/max-len
  'max-len': ['warn', { code: 150, ignoreComments: false, ignoreRegExpLiterals: true, ignoreStrings: true, ignoreTemplateLiterals: true }],

  // https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-lines
  'max-lines': ['error', { max: 300, skipBlankLines: true, skipComments: true }],

  // https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-lines-per-function
  'max-lines-per-function': ['error', { max: 30, skipBlankLines: true, skipComments: true }],

  // https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-console
  // 'no-console': ['error', { allow: ['warn', 'error'] }],
  'no-console': ['warn'],

  'no-inline-comments': 'off',
  'no-warning-comments': 'off',
  'object-curly-newline': 'off',
  'object-property-newline': 'off',
  'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': [
    'warn',
    {
      additionalHooks: '(useRecoilCallback|useRecoilTransaction_UNSTABLE)', // https://recoiljs.org/docs/introduction/installation#eslint
    },
  ],
};

const config: Linter.Config = [
  ...compat.extends('@next/next/recommended', 'canonical/prettier'),
  // TODO: eslint rules for jest, if the Next.js rules don't handle it.
  ...compat.extends('canonical', 'canonical/prettier'),
  ...compat.extends('canonical/json', 'canonical/prettier').map((item: Linter.Config) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      files: ['*.json'],
    };
  }),
  ...compat.extends('canonical/yaml', 'canonical/prettier').map((item: Linter.Config) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      files: ['*.yaml'],
    };
  }),
  // TODO: This section seems to conflict with the `tsParser` section. What's the best way to combine them or eliminate whatever isn't necessary?
  // ...compat.extends('canonical/typescript', 'canonical/prettier').map((item: Linter.Config) => {
  //   return {
  //     ...item,
  //     files: ['*.ts'],
  //     languageOptions: {
  //       parser: tsParser, // Is there a way to find this within `item` instead of importing it separately?
  //       parserOptions: {
  //         project: './tsconfig.json',
  //       },
  //     },
  //   };
  // }),
  {
    files: ['{**/{index,_app}.tsx,next.config.js,**/eslint.config.js,**/eslint.config.ts,pages/*.tsx}'],
    rules: {
      'canonical/filename-match-exported': 'off',
    },
  },
  {
    rules: {
      'canonical/destructuring-property-newline': 'off',
      'canonical/import-specifier-newline': 'off',
      'import/extensions': [
        'error',
        {
          css: 'always',
          js: 'never',
          json: 'always',
          jsx: 'never',
          mjs: 'never',
          ts: 'never',
          tsx: 'never',
        },
      ],
      'import/no-unassigned-import': [
        'error',
        {
          allow: ['**/*.css'],
        },
      ],
      'import/order': [
        'error',
        {
          alphabetize: {
            caseInsensitive: false,
            order: 'asc',
          },
          groups: ['builtin', 'external', 'internal', 'parent', 'sibling', 'index'],
          'newlines-between': 'always',
          warnOnUnassignedImports: false,
        },
      ],
      'jsdoc/valid-types': 'off',
    },
  },
  {
    rules: {
      'import/extensions': [
        // https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/extensions.md#importextensions
        'off',
        {
          'nextauth]': 'never',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    ignores: ['.next/*'],
  },
  {
    files: ['**/*.ts', '**/*.tsx'],
    languageOptions: {
      parser: tsParser,
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: {
          modules: true,
        },
        ecmaVersion: 'latest',
        project: './tsconfig.json',
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      '@typescript-eslint': typeScriptEslintPlugin,
      functional,
      // import: eslintPluginImport,
      ts: typeScriptEslintPlugin,
    },
    rules: {
      ...typeScriptEslintPlugin.configs['eslint-recommended'].rules,
      ...typeScriptEslintPlugin.configs.recommended.rules,
      'ts/return-await': 'error', // https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/return-await/
    },
  },
  {
    files: ['*.json'],
    rules: {
      'jsonc/sort-keys': 'off',
    },
  },
  {
    files: ['**/*.ts', '**/*.tsx', '**/*.js', '**/*.jsx'],
    languageOptions: {
      globals: {
        ...globals.browser,
        ...globals.node,
      },
    },
    rules: {
      ...customRules,
    },
  },
];

const innerConfigs: Linter.Config = Object.values(config);
for (const innerConfig of innerConfigs) {
  console.log(innerConfig.rules);
}

export default config;
```

How would *you* accomplish what I'm trying to do? Thanks.

Comment: Have you made progress on this? I stumbled here looking for how to configure Jest with a flat eslint config.

Comment: @trusktr I started looking at https://github.com/eslint/eslint/discussions/17228#discussioncomment-6026225 but didn't make quick progress.